# Should my custom keyboard's "delete all" button have an image?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am making a custom iOS keyboard. Here is the current design:

[image: currentkeyboardformat]

The "delete all text" button (the one with the x that is surrounded by a square) is currently the only key on the keyboard that has an image instead of text. Should I make its function more clear by replacing the image with text?

Comment: It's not a possible duplicate, it's definitely a duplicate: Same author, same question, same app but different platform. Both questions were asked on and migrated from graphicdesign.stackexchange.com. I vote to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the fact that I know, by reading your description, that your **X**-button would "delete all text" I would come the conclusion that pressing the **X**-button would close/minimize your keyboard.

Using just an icon works great when the icon is put in the right context, just look at the google seach bar in your image.

In your case I would suggest at least adding a text next to your icon. Also: "delete all text" is quite abstract. Consider using the word **Clear** instead of delete.

Comment: Or possibly use the iOS delete icon.

Answer (score 1):

According to The Nielsen Norman Group, icons need text labels. [Read their article here.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/) It's very good.

So yes, you'll need the label. Whether or not you keep the icon is almost irrelevant, but it does stick out in an odd way since it's the only one on the screen.

It's also not clear what text it's going to delete. (The text in the entry field? That field already has a clear command, the "x.")